# Как узнать, что у пользователя прервалась связь websocket?

Tags: php, websocket, javascript

Использую websocket на сайте и когда у меня например пропадает интернет никаких событий не происходит, onerror и onclose молчат на сервере и на клиенте. Как узнать что у пользователя прервалась связь клиенту и серверу?
На сервере вебсокет запущен на php с помощью Ratchet.

Comment: нужно делать "пинги". Если пинги не пришли за какое-то время - связи нет.

Comment: @KoVadim пинг-понгами? А как серверу узнать что соединение пропало?

Comment: как, не пришел ping в socket. ping можно  делать так (socket.io):

на клиенте 

    var lastreply=0;
     socket.on('pong',function(){
        lastreply=new Date();
     });
     setInterval(function(){
     if (new Date()-lastreply>20000) connection_lost(); //(20 секунд)
     socket.emit('ping')`
     },10000);

на сервере подписываетесь на событие ping и отправляете в тот-же сокет pong.

Comment: ну ещё на уровне socket.io реализованы timeout и heartbeat.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    echo "User disconnected! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
}
```

Comment: "onerror и onclose молчат на сервере и на клиенте"